# Make prompt only display directory when not at $HOME?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, prompt

I'd like to prevent my terminal prompt from displaying the directory I'm in when I'm at my home directory.

I'm using `zsh`. This is my prompt config:

```
PROMPT=''

# Formatting
PROMPT+='%F{8}' # dark grey

# Non zero exit codes
PROMPT+='%(?..[Exit code %?] )'

# PID when relevant
if [[ $! -ne 0 ]]; then
    PROMPT+='[PID $!] '
fi

# Current dir path
PROMPT+='[%~] '

# Formatting reset
PROMPT+='%f' # color reset
```

Answer (score 3):

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT+='$([[ $PWD != $HOME ]] && echo "[%~] ")'
```

#### Explanation

- `setopt PROMPT_SUBST` enables *parameter expansion* (`$name`), *command substitution* (`$(command)`) and *arithmetic expansion* (`$[exp]` or `$((exp))`) within the prompt
- PROMPT+='…' appends to the prompt. Note that you need to use single quotes here so that the contents are not expanded during definiton but only when the prompt is shown.
- `$(command)` runs `command` and substitutes its output, e.g. `$(echo foo)` would be replaced with "foo".
- `[[ exp ]]` evaluates a conditional expression. It will return zero only if the expression is true. Note that `[[ exp ]]` is built-in syntax of `zsh`, while the similar `[ exp ]` would run the external `[` (aka `test`) command.
- `PWD` contains the current working directory.
- `HOME` contains the home directory of the current user.
- `!=` tests for inequality.
- `&&` runs the command to the right only if the command to the left was successful (that is, returned zero)
- `echo "[%~] "` prints the (partial) prompt string. Note that double quotes are used so that the surrounding single quotes are not closed prematurely.